# Clojure form to string

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to convert a Clojure form to a string?
E.g. convert:

```
(and (f 1) (g 3))
```

to:

```
"(and (f 1) (g 3))"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
=> (defmacro string-it [x] (str x))
#'user/string-it
=> (string-it (+ 1 2))
"(+ 1 2)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
(str '(and (f 1) (g 3)))
```

EDIT

In case you're not familiar with it, the `'` ("quote") character is a reader macro character ([more](http://clojure.org/reader)) that escapes code -- i.e. keeps it from being evaluated.

You could also set a variable:

```
(def x '(and (f 1) (g 3)))
(str x)
```

and then if you wanted to run the code you could eval it.

Answer (score 3):

Alternativly if you don't know the form before hand you can do,

```
(defmacro to-str [f]
  (str f))

(to-str (and (f 1) (g 3)))
```

and get,

```
"(and (f 1) (g 3))"
```