# Clojure String to Form

Tags: string, forms, clojure

I would like to convert a string to a form in clojure.  Something like

```
(defn string-to-form [string]
   ;; some magic here
   converted-to-form)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003103/clojure-form-to-string) has the opposite direction, namely form to string.  How to I go the other way?

Comment: did you tried read-sting..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey if i am correct your want to know

```
"(+ 1 2)" ;=> (+ 1 2)
```

if these is you problem then you can use read-string from clojure.core

```
(defn string-to-form [string] (read-string string))
```